# How can I display a string output from mySQL with CakePHP?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have a database system set up to store and output pages and posts in my CMS,
however I am getting this returned from the database:

```
&lt;p&gt;&amp;lt;iframe width=&quot;854&quot; height=&quot;480&quot; src=&quot;https://www.youtube.com/embed/PMf6PjVXRtc&quot; frameborder=&quot;0&quot; allowfullscreen&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/iframe&amp;gt;&lt;/p&gt;
```

At this point I have removed all encoding - it's just a straight CakePHP ->Save,
and this appears to be the result of CakePHP's data sanitization.

```
        $this->save(
            array(
                'contentBody' => $data["contentBody"]
            ),
            false
        );
```

On the output side, what can I do to properly display this encoded HTML? The output may include regular echo or print, as well as a TinyMCE textarea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `html_entity_decode()` before doing output. Lets say you are having output html in a variable `$str` use the following like for outputting:

```
echo html_entity_decode(html_entity_decode($str));
```

Comment: I already am in one spot at least, that produces this:                               <iframe width="854" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/PMf6PjVXRtc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>       I have a feeling I'm missing something else as well.

Comment: Okay, using echo html_entity_decode($Post['Post']['contentBody']); on a plain HTML page produces the above string instead of the expected iframe output, which should display a Youtube embedded video.

Comment: I have edited my code above. Use `html_entity_decode()` twice on the string because cake php is encoding twice. If you find your solution mark my answer as solved and vote it up :) Thanks

Comment: Well that's one part of the issue solved. I did not honestly expect that to work in a html/php output. Now for the second half, I have to figure out why I can't get the same display in TinyMCE.

Comment: how you are outputting to tinymce ?

Comment: Figured it out! I was accidentally using 'input' instead of 'textarea'/, and outputting the value into an input "value=" string instead of the blank space between textarea brackets. Had a moment of thought on that and decided to try replacing the form type, and it works!

Comment: No wonder I wasn't getting the correct output right. Anything I did was actually triple-or quad-encoding the HTML for pages and posts. As far as I can tell, the documentation does not directly mention that CakePHP double-encodes